# Create list of cells that have value in adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have several (10 to be exact) worksheets in a document formatted like this that each correspond to a class:

```
| Name | Time 1 | Time 2 | Time 3 | Time 4 |
--------------------------------------------
| Jack | Place1 | Place2 | Place3 | Place4 |
| John | Place4 | Place6 | Place2 | Place9 |
| Dave | Place8 | Place2 | Place5 | Place1 |
```

which contain information for people, where they belong at the given time (like a timetable). There is around 25 people in each class and 9 different places. What I need to do is create 4x9 tables (for each place and time) which will list all the people which are at that time in the given place. So it will be like this:

```
On one sheet:
Place 1 - Time 1
| Name | Signature |
--------------------
| Jack |           |
| Some |           | <--- this guy is from a different class (sheet)


On another sheet:
Place 2 - Time 2
| Name |           |
--------------------
| Jack |           |
| Dave |           |
| Mark |           | <--- again, another class
```

It can be anything, a macro, VBS, functions, whatever, that really doesn't matter. If it helps in any way to, I don't know, correctly size the new tables, I already have a table containing the number of people at each place and time. Unfortunately, I can't do it by hand, it is too much data...

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are happy to assist, but this is not a service site where we do the work for you. This is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, it was done by this formula. I will replace the variables with their explanation. It is pfooo long but it is actually pretty easy. Please ignore the Czech versions of the functions, `KDYŽ`=`IF`, `ŘÁDEK`=`ROW` and `ŘÁDKY`=`ROWS`.

```
IFERROR(INDEX(Prima;SMALL(KDYŽ(A$1=Prima[Blok 1];ŘÁDEK(Prima[Blok 1])-3);ŘÁDKY(A$3:A3));1);
IFERROR(INDEX(Sekunda;SMALL(KDYŽ(A$1=Sekunda[Blok 1];ŘÁDEK(Sekunda[Blok 1])-3);ŘÁDKY(A$3:A3)-COUNTIF(Prima[Blok 1];A$1));1);
IFERROR(INDEX(TercieA;SMALL(KDYŽ(A$1=TercieA[Blok 1];ŘÁDEK(TercieA[Blok 1])-3);ŘÁDKY(A$3:A3)-COUNTIF(Prima[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Sekunda[Blok 1];A$1));1);
IFERROR(INDEX(TercieB;SMALL(KDYŽ(A$1=TercieB[Blok 1];ŘÁDEK(TercieB[Blok 1])-3);ŘÁDKY(A$3:A3)-COUNTIF(Prima[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Sekunda[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(TercieA[Blok 1];A$1));1);
IFERROR(INDEX(Kvarta;SMALL(KDYŽ(A$1=Kvarta[Blok 1];ŘÁDEK(Kvarta[Blok 1])-3);ŘÁDKY(A$3:A3)-COUNTIF(Prima[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Sekunda[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(TercieA[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(TercieB[Blok 1];A$1));1);
IFERROR(INDEX(KvintaA;SMALL(KDYŽ(A$1=KvintaA[Blok 1];ŘÁDEK(KvintaA[Blok 1])-3);ŘÁDKY(A$3:A3)-COUNTIF(Prima[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Sekunda[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(TercieA[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(TercieB[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Kvarta[Blok 1];A$1));1);
IFERROR(INDEX(KvintaB;SMALL(KDYŽ(A$1=KvintaB[Blok 1];ŘÁDEK(KvintaB[Blok 1])-3);ŘÁDKY(A$3:A3)-COUNTIF(Prima[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Sekunda[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(TercieA[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(TercieB[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Kvarta[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(KvintaA[Blok 1];A$1));1);
IFERROR(INDEX(Sexta;SMALL(KDYŽ(A$1=Sexta[Blok 1];ŘÁDEK(Sexta[Blok 1])-3);ŘÁDKY(A$3:A3)-COUNTIF(Prima[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Sekunda[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(TercieA[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(TercieB[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Kvarta[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(KvintaA[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(KvintaB[Blok 1];A$1));1);
IFERROR(INDEX(Septima;SMALL(KDYŽ(A$1=Septima[Blok 1];ŘÁDEK(Septima[Blok 1])-3);ŘÁDKY(A$3:A3)-COUNTIF(Prima[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Sekunda[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(TercieA[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(TercieB[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Kvarta[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(KvintaA[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(KvintaB[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Sexta[Blok 1];A$1));1);
IFERROR(INDEX(Oktáva;SMALL(KDYŽ(A$1=Oktáva[Blok 1];ŘÁDEK(Oktáva[Blok 1])-3);ŘÁDKY(A$3:A3)-COUNTIF(Prima[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Sekunda[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(TercieA[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(TercieB[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Kvarta[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(KvintaA[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(KvintaB[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Sexta[Blok 1];A$1)-COUNTIF(Septima[Blok 1];A$1));1);""
```

))))))))))

The main part is repeated there several times, as an alternative text for the `IFERROR()` function:

```
IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        <table range>;
        SMALL(
            IF(
                <value to find>=<range in table to look in>;
                ROW(<range in table to look in>)-<number of rows above the first row of the table>
            );
            ROWS(<first-cell-in-results-column-to-this-cell range>) <note here>
        );
        <column number (starting from 1) with the return value>
    );
    <alternative for IFERROR>
)
```

The above formula will, if values are set properly, return all values from return column if the correct value is found in the search range. Now if you need to accomplish what I needed, that is to get values from multiple tables into single list, you need to set this formula as the alternative for the `IFERROR`, once for each source table.

That is good but it isn't the only thing we need to do. This formula works by internally creating an array of return values inside each cell of list and then selecting Nth smallest index (the `INDEX` function) from it where N is set by the `ROWS` function inside the `INDEX`. So if we didn't do the following it would, when continuing to the next table, try again to select the Nth index, however there are already some values from the previous tables. We need to subtract the amount of items already present in the table using the `COUNTIF` function. So after we add the second iteration of our formula, the whole thing will look like this:

```
IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        <table range>;
        SMALL(
            IF(
                <value to find>=<range in table to look in>;
                ROW(<range in table to look in>)-<number of rows above the first row of the table>
            );
            ROWS(<first-cell-in-results-column-to-this-cell range>)
        );
        <column number (starting from 1) with the return value>
    );
    IFERROR(
        INDEX(
            <table 2 range>;
            SMALL(
                IF(
                    <value to find>=<range in table 2 to look in>;
                    ROW(<range in table 2 to look in>)-<number of rows above the first row of the table 2>
                );
                ROWS(<first-cell-in-results-column-to-this-cell range>)
                -COUNTIF(<range in table 2 to look in>; <value to find>)
            );
            <column number (starting from 1) with the return value>
        );
        <another iteration or something else>
    )
)
```

And with every new iteration inside next `IFERROR` we have to add another `-COUNTIF` function and KEEP the previous ones. Then, when everything is set up, you can just drag your formula actoss the board and create lists all you want!

I really hope this helps someone, if it does feel free to leave a comment :) I have put some time into this formula and figuring out how things work so if I saved you some time, I was happy to help! :)